# PHP mySQL Showing Posts in Friend List

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, facebook

First of all, I want to say that, I am not good to explain technical issue but I will try :)

I am trying to do something like facebook wall. I have 4 tables.

1. Users
2. User Pictures
3. Friend List
4. Share Posts

I want to show user's friends posts on his/her homepage. I searched and found some solutions and applied to my application. But I am trying to find alternative way for SQL query. Because I used sub-query and maybe this can be made without this.

Here is database: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbacd

SQL code for getting results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT share.*, member.*, picture.file
FROM friend
LEFT JOIN share ON share.wall_owner_id = friend.friend_id
LEFT JOIN picture ON picture.member_id = share.wall_owner_id
LEFT JOIN member ON member.member_id = share.wall_owner_id
WHERE friend_id IN (SELECT friend_id FROM friend WHERE member_id = 'MEMBER.ID')
OR share.writed_by_id = 'MEMBER.ID'
```

**MEMBER.ID** = Logged-in user's ID.

Friendship design working as cross system.
If someone accept friend request (table not added to sqlfiddle), both are writing to database as friends like 2, 8 and 8, 2. Is it good way to do like that?

Thank you very much.

Friendly.

Comment: Aren't the shares with 'wall_owner_id' matching MEMBER.ID the shares that should be displayed?

Comment: Or do you want to show everything that was posted on the walls of 'MEMBER_ID's all friends?

Comment: Yes, I want to show everything was posted by MEMBER.ID and MEMBER.ID's friends. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do this without this extra join. Still not sure if I got the requirements right. This kind of query should work if you want to see everything that was posted by his friends or him on any wall. Basically you just select those persons that have MEMBER.ID as friend or are MEMBER.ID themselves.

```
SELECT DISTINCT share.share_id, share.status_text
FROM friend
JOIN share ON share.writed_by_id = friend.member_id
JOIN picture ON picture.member_id = share.wall_owner_id
WHERE friend.friend_id = 2 OR friend.member_id = 2
```